# Illegal assignment from List<SmartlyStreetApex> to SmartlyStreetApex error while executing code

Tags: apex, json, callout, httprequest

Through JSON converter i made the following wrapper class:

```
public class SmartlyStreetApex {

    public class Components {
        public String primary_number;
        public String street_predirection;
        public String street_name;
        public String street_suffix;
        public String city_name;
        public String default_city_name;
        public String state_abbreviation;
        public String zipcode;
        public String plus4_code;
        public String delivery_point;
        public String delivery_point_check_digit;
    }

    public Integer input_index;
    public Integer candidate_index;
    public String delivery_line_1;
    public String last_line;
    public String delivery_point_barcode;
    public Components components;
    public Metadata metadata;
    public Analysis analysis;

    public class Analysis {
        public String dpv_match_code;
        public String dpv_footnotes;
        public String dpv_cmra;
        public String dpv_vacant;
        public String active;
    }

    public class Metadata {
        public String record_type;
        public String zip_type;
        public String county_fips;
        public String county_name;
        public String carrier_route;
        public String congressional_district;
        public String rdi;
        public String elot_sequence;
        public String elot_sort;
        public Double latitude;
        public Double longitude;
        public String precision;
        public String time_zone;
        public Integer utc_offset;
        public Boolean dst;
    }


    public static List<SmartlyStreetApex> parse(String json) {
        return (List<SmartlyStreetApex>) System.JSON.deserialize(json, List<SmartlyStreetApex>.class);
    }
}
```

And I am running execute anonymous code to execute

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-street-api?auth-id=**************-8a4e-58918b40f0ca&auth-token=***AjFGDps');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
if(response.getStatusCode() == 200)
{
    system.debug(response.getBody());
    SmartlyStreetApex result= SmartlyStreetApex.parse(response.getBody());
    //system.debug('result'+result);
}
```

I am getting below error-

> Line: 9, Column: 22 Illegal assignment from List to SmartlyStreetApex

Can someone check this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value is a list, so you need to use that same type:

```
List<SmartlyStreetApex> result= SmartlyStreetApex.parse(response.getBody());
```

Or, as I prefer, the shorter syntax:

```
SmartlyStreetApex[] result= SmartlyStreetApex.parse(response.getBody());
```

Comment: The first one I used thanks for this I also added this :)